# Category Theory fundamentals

Tags: haskell, category-theory

I am looking for references on Category Theory that

- are mature (== at least 5 years old)
- at a level of university education (not post-doctorate, ultra symbolic introductions)
- start from the basics (Abelian Group, Set theory known - similar level) and avoid introducing new terms before defining them (counterexample: Wikipedia, as if you take any definitions, you will understand that now you have to look up an exponentially increasing number of words)
- preferably support a full conceptual understanding that is useful for both Haskell and the corresponding mathematics as well

The problem I am trying to solve is: maximizing the use of paradigms and features of Haskell (instead of blindly accepting that this is e.g. an Applicative, so what.) I am using (or eventually going to use) Haskell in automated reasoning.

I put all these explicitly there so that we can avoid flagging with

- Primarily opinion based (these are very explicit criteria)
- Product Recommendation (since I am asking for mature references, answers will not become quickly obsolete)

Comment: https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/10/28/category-theory-for-programmers-the-preface/
Along with the lectures https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8LbkfSSR58&list=PLbgaMIhjbmEnaH_LTkxLI7FMa2HsnawM_ (there's also part 2 and 3).

Comment: I suggest [Emily Riehl's *Category Theory in Context*](https://math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/context/). (michid's recommendation is also very good.)

Comment: @duplode: Awesome, thanks! This is a more advanced material, but I will find good use of it!

Comment: This is not really answering my question (mostly mathematics), but seems to be a low level, nicely paced introduction with examples, so I just leave it here as a comment: [Conceptual Mathematics - A First Introduction to Categories](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/conceptual-mathematics/00772F4CC3D4268200C5EC86B39D415A)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My opinion:

The Harold Simmons - "An introduction to Category theory" - Cambridge University Press, 2011. Is a good start to Category theory.

^ This introductory book is only 200 pages but does what you request. It targeted for undergraduates and starts from basics and explains the most of the terms of clean math of the Category theory. 200 pages basically to form the view of the field. (and to read back afterward). Not just my word (I write the Haskell-Cat book of my own): Chris Allen, one of the authors of "Haskell Programming from First Principles", pointed out in his talks that it is a good Category theory learning material he cracked the theory through.

Bartosz Milewski - "Category Theory for Programmers". And his open lectures. He is amazing, but I think briefly reading through the 200 books first would make his material and to learn it, understand, evaluated, and so recorded, remembered better.

Then what you interested in is:
David I. Spivak - "Category Theory for the Sciences" - The MIT Press, 2014. It talks less about the theory, but gives better examples of the applications. Spivak's name already talks for itself, he is known as the "Applied Category theory" guy.

I think the order or cross-over sequencing of them is not as important, it depends on how the mind of a person works and what path the person goes to reside.

Comment: David I. Spivak - "Category Theory for the Sciences" is great but not specifically targeted towards programmers. However, there is "Programming with Categories" from  Brendan Fong, Bartosz Milewski, and David Spivak, which is quite good: http://brendanfong.com/programmingcats.html

Comment: I just consider the problem with Cat, besides of hard abstraction of the theory, is to see it in things and apply it. There is a number of books around Programming with Cats, but because of the "programming" theme attached to the book - they destined go to into examples of implementation, and people learning the code examples can't see the wood for the trees. The question definitely needs to be approached from both high-level understanding and solid abstract knowledge.
And because people comment, I provided mine ansver.

Comment: David I. Spivak is also a coauthor of [*Seven Sketches in Compositionality: An Invitation to Applied Category Theory*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.05316), whose approach is perhaps rather different to what is specified in the question here, but it is a very enjoyable book nonetheless.

Comment: Awesome! I have just purchased and started to read "An introduction to Category theory", but it uses (and takes granted the knowledge of) many terms right from the beginning, so probably I will start with the Milewski lectures and will revisit this e-book after that. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Well, I know none of the more straightforward book that gives such concise catalog for Category abstractions that would frequently be encountered.

It is not possible to go easier in such a concise manner.

People often refer to the classic Mac Lane's "Categories for the Working Mathematician", that is a book "that goes rather steep".

Well, then Milewski it is, but his book is simplistic, never done and the first print was 1.5-2 years ago, so I thought it did not fit the requirements.

Well, "An introduction to Category theory" is a great book nevertheless.